# How to get xml element using element value?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to get xml element using element value and I have to get parent element with xml element using jaxb?

**sample XML:**

```
 <ifx>
<nam-ref>LID</nam-ref>
<val>01</val>
<then>
    <int>
        <name>WHEELSPEED</name>
        <description></description>            
    </int>
    <int>
        <name>FRONT</name>
        <description></description>
    </int>
    <manyInt>
        <int>
            <name>REAR_LEFT</name>
            <description></description>
        </int>
    </manyInt>
    <int>
        <name>REAR_RIGHT</name>        
    </int>
</then>
```

I know only the name value as "REAR_LEFT". With this I have find the xml element and its parent element .

Comment: Does it need to be jaxb? This shouts imho for XPath or data projection.

Comment: Its good to be in JAXb, other ways also fine

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with JAXB if you have a schema and generate a lot of classes and iterate through each of the attributes to find the value you search for.
Or you use a little [data projection](http://xmlbeam.org) (Disclosure: I'm affiliated with that project):

```
import org.xmlbeam.XBProjector;
import org.xmlbeam.XBProjector.Flags;
import org.xmlbeam.annotation.XBRead;

public class Demo {

    public interface Projection {

        @XBRead("name()")
        String getType();

        @XBRead("./name")
        String getName();

        @XBRead("./description")
        String getDescription();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xpath="//*[name='REAR_LEFT']";
        Projection projection = new XBProjector(Flags.TO_STRING_RENDERS_XML).io().url("res://data.xml").evalXPath(xpath).as(Projection.class);
        System.out.println(projection.getType()+":"+projection.getName()+" "+projection.getDescription());
        System.out.println("As XML:\n"+projection);
    }

}
```

After correction of you XML (add a root element, close the ifx element) this program prints out:

```
int:REAR_LEFT 
As XML:
<int>
    <name>REAR_LEFT</name>
    <description/>
</int>
```

This is how it works:

- The xpath `//*[name='REAR_LEFT']` selects every element that has a child named "name" with the content "REAR_LEFT".
- The XBProjector "projects" the selected element to the Java interface `Projection`
- The projection interface can access the data in the element by defined projection methods (e.g. for type, name & description=
- The projection interface can print itself out as XML

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I need one more help of finding the parent element of int ie manyInt

Comment: If you need to go one step up to the parent of int, just append ".." as step expression: `//*[name='REAR_LEFT']/..`